# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'

Tags: android, cordova, quasar-framework

I'm using Quasar (Vue js framework) to build an android app.
I'm following the documentation to build my app.

When I try to run this command `quasar build -m cordova -T android` it fails with some warning and errors.

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @64a7768e

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 43s
12 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 10 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\projects\galaxy-ecommerce-app\src-cordova\platforms\android\gradlew :app:bundleRelease -b C:\Users\Admin\Do
cuments\projects\galaxy-ecommerce-app\src-cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle
```

Comment: Hello @Hasibur Rahman did you find any solution for this problem? i am also facing this problem. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, somehow I fixed it. But I can't clearly remember how I did this.

Comment: @tiana did you find a solution to above, been bugging me now for days. And Hasibur could you please try and highlight possible solutions. Thanks

Comment: hey @Johhn sorry i did not recall how i fixed step by step but i do remember downgrading my Gradle to  --> Gradle(7.0) and android Gradle plugin Version(4.2.1).